# Migrate/Copy a database using automap_base and alembic

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, alembic

I have a database `x` with some amount of data filled in every tables. I want to create a copy of that database (with same schema and exact data). First I create a Declaritive Base class of `x` using automap_base.

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session as s

def name_for_scalar_relationship(base, local_cls, referred_cls, constraint):
    name = referred_cls.__name__.lower() + "_ref"
    return name

Base = automap_base()

# engine, refering to the original database
engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://root:password1@localhost:3306/x")

# reflect the tables
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True, name_for_scalar_relationship=name_for_scalar_relationship)

Router = Base.classes.router
########check the data in Router table
session = s(engine)
r1 = session.query(Router).all()
for n in r1:
    print(n.name)   #This returns all the router names
```

Getting some help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24412627/alembic-create-table-using-declarative-base-derived-objects) I use `alembic` to upgrade the database `y` located at different place `mysql+pymysql://anum:Anum-6630@localhost:3306/y`.

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker as sm
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from alembic import op

# revision identifiers, used by Alembic.
revision = 'fae98f65a6ff'
down_revision = None
branch_labels = None
depends_on = None


def upgrade():
    bind = op.get_bind()
    session = sm(bind=bind)
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=bind)

    # session._add_bind(session, bind=bind)
    session.add(Router(id=uuid.uuid().bytes, serial="Test1"))
    session.commit()
```

The line `Base.metadata.create_all(bind=bind)` actually add all the tables (including proper FK constraints) into database `y`, but all the tables are empty, except one entry in Router table which I added manually. I tried using create_all() but that didn't worked aswel. 
Is there a way to copy all the data from `x` to `y` database ?

Answer (score 0):

Since no one answered, here is my wild method that does the copying:
Because the tables needs to be created in order (to avoid FK constraints errors), I have to define an ordered-list containing each table

**Slow and NOT reliable solution:**

```
allTables = ["tableA", 
             "tableB", # <table B points to FK constraint of tableA>
             "tableC", # <table C points to FK constraint of tableB>
             ...]

def copyAllContent():
    global allTables
    s = Session(bind=origEngine)  # session bind to original table
    se = Session(bind=op.get_bind()) # session bind to cloned table (currently empty)
try:
    for table in allTables:
        # print(table)
        rows = s.query(Base.classes._data[table]).all()
        for row in rows:
            local_object = se.merge(row)  #merging both sessions
            se.add(local_object)
            se.commit()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

The above method worked for most of the tables, but not all. e.g. table `router` existed in original database, but still I get errors in `s.query(Base.classes._data[table]).all()` no key exists with name `router`. Haven't got enough time to dig down to the solution for that.

**FAST and Reliable solution:**

Later on I found [from here](https://webcheatsheet.com/SQL/mysql_backup_restore.php) another FAST and quiet reliable solution using `mysqldump`

```
#copy sql dump from x database
mysqldump --column-statistics=0 -P 8000 -h localhost -u root -p --hex-blob x > x_dump.sql
```

The above command-line `mysqldump` command creates a sql dump file named `x_dump.sql` which contains all the necessary SQL scripts required to re-generate your database. Now All we need to do is apply this sql dump file to another database `y`

```
#clone the database contents into y database
mysql -P 3306 -h localhost -u anum -p y < x_dump.sql
```

Here is pythonic version of doing the same

```
import subprocess

#copy sql dump from x database - blocking call (use Popen for non-blocking)
print(subprocess.call(["mysqldump", "--column-statistics=0", '-P', '8000', '-h', 'localhost', '-u', '<user>', '-p<password>',
                        '--hex-blob', 'x', '>', 'x_dump.sql'], shell=True))

print("done taking dump.")

#clone the database contents into y database - blocking call
print(subprocess.call(["mysql", '-P', '3306', '-h', 'localhost', '-u', '<user>', '-p<password>',
                        'y', '<', 'x_dump.sql'], shell=True))

print("done cloning the sqlDump.")
```

Comment: mysqldump version that I am using is 8.0.12. Whereas if you're trying newer version 10.x.xx. don't provide `--column-statistics=0` argument. Also remove `shell=True` from python script.